# WPF DataGrid - Virtualised - select all

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable

With a WPF virtualised DataGrid I need to employ a 'select all' method. Iterating though the grid itself won't work as it will only select the records that at visible in the UI - but of course if they are selected using the mouse they are retained. I'm guessing that something must change in the DataTable, but what? If so can it be manipulated so that all the records are selected in the DataGrid?

Thanks

======================== ADDED===========================

Eran - thanks for your reply but having a job wiring this up

1. Create DataGrid

   ```
    Dim DGV As New CustomControl.DGVx
       With DGV
           .Name = "Invoice_AdHoc_DGV"
           .AutoGenerateColumns = False
           .SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple
       End With
       RegisterControl(Invoice_AdHoc_Grid, DGV)
       RightGrid.Children.Add(DGV)
   ```
2. Bind to DataTable

   ```
   DGV.ItemsSource = AdHocDT.DefaultView
   ```
3. Created the class from your answer

   ```
   Public Class ObjectSelectAll
   Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
   Public Property Name() As String
   Private vIsSelected As Boolean
   Public Property IsSelected() As Boolean
   Get
       Return vIsSelected
   End Get
   Set(value As Boolean)
       vIsSelected = value
       RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"))
   End Set
   End Property


   Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
   ```

   End Class

Comment: i would use a select all logic on my .cs objects and not on the visual objects , what do you mean by selected , do you have a chekcbox column bound to some IsSelected property ?

Comment: Clicking on the row selects it (IsSelected = True) - I would like to do the same thing if the user clicks a 'select all' button. Is there a way to do this with the DataTable?

Comment: you could create a row style which indicates a value from your  objects bound to a rows IsSelected and them when clicking select all 
update the bound propertyin your objects . 
as for the UI only the "Realized" objects would be viewably "Selected"

Comment: I can iterate though the DataTable and get the required result, but it would be great if the change in colour/font could also be replicated in the DataGrid as though it was a mouse selected row - everything I have tried only works for the visible part of the UI.

Comment: the answer iv'e given you selectes the rows , and is visible in the UI .

Comment: I am assuming (and this may be where I have it all wrong) that something changes in the backend DataTable when the user selects a row - so that when it scrolls back into view it is still showing as selected?

Comment: the bound object that gets visulaized updates the IsSelected state of the row via binding.

Comment: What are the objects (obj1, obj2, obj3...) that you are referring to?

Comment: they are my grid's ItemsSource

Comment: If the ItemsSource is a DataTable how do I wire that in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to resolve this issue

Added another column to the DataTable

```
 With AdHocDT.Columns
                 .Add("Selected", GetType(Boolean))
            End With
```

When 'Select All' is clicked set this to True for all rows and in the Grid the value is updated to true as well, then add this to ensure that the Grid shows it as selected when the virtual data is scrolled into view

```
Private Sub Invoice_AdHoc_DGV_ItemsChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim DGV As CustomControl.DGVx = Invoice_AdHoc_Grid.FindName("Invoice_AdHoc_DGV")
        Dim i As Integer = 0
         For Each Row As DataRowView In DGV.Items
            Dim vRow As DevComponents.WPF.Controls.AdvGridRow = CType(DGV.ItemContainerManager.ContainerFromItem(DGV.Items(i), False), DevComponents.WPF.Controls.AdvGridRow)
            If Not vRow Is Nothing Then
                If Row("Selected") = True Then
                    vRow.IsSelected = True
                End If
            End If
            i += 1
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

and handle the event

```
AddHandler DGV.ItemContainerManager.VisibleContainersChanged, AddressOf Invoice_AdHoc_DGV_ItemsChanged
```

Now the Grid shows all the rows as selected :-)

Answer (score 0):

cs :

```
    private List<MyObject> _items;
    public List<MyObject> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if(_items == null)
                _items = new List<MyObject> { new MyObject { Name = "obj1" }, new MyObject { Name = "obj2" }, new MyObject { Name = "obj3" }, new MyObject { Name = "obj4" } };
            return _items;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}

public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

xaml :

```
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Content="Select All"/>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>                    
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>    
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```